# Altering multiple input's id's using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the id's of all of the check boxes inside of a parent container, but thus far I have ot been able to get it to work, here is my code,

HTML:

```
<div data-custom='other_container' class='container'>
<h3>Other:</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <label for='monitoring'>Monitoring and verification of energy savings: </label>
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='other' id='monitoring' class='validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox' />
  </div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <label for='engineering'>Engineering & project management: </label>
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='other' id='engineering' class='validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox' />
  </div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <label for='energy_audits'>Energy audits: </label>
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='other' id='energy_audits' class='validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox' />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("[data-custom='other_container']").children('input').attr('id', 'test');
```

Any idea on what could be wrong with this?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data-custom='other_container'` element doesn't have any *children* that are `<input>` elements.

You should [use `.find()` instead](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
$("[data-custom='other_container']").find('input').attr('id', 'test');
```

The `.find()` method will search through all descendants, [whereas `.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only looks at immediate children.

But keep in mind that IDs must be unique, so you will want to be sure to assign a unique ID to each. You could do something like this:

```
$("[data-custom='other_container']").find('input').attr('id', function( i ) {
       return 'test' + i;
});
```

Also, it is a good idea to give the `div` tag name in the selector in this case, so jQuery isn't looking at *every* element for the `data-custom` attribute.

```
$("div[data-custom='other_container']")
```

You could also make it a little more specific by adding the `.container` class to the selector.

```
$("div.container[data-custom='other_container']")
```

Answer (score 0):

`data-custom` don't have any children that are `<input>`

You can use this instead -

```
$("[data-custom='other_container'] input").attr('id', 'test');
```

The above code will search `<input>` in all childrens , grand-childrens and so on and replace their id. The code you have used searches only in children of `data-custom`

Your code is equivalent to -

```
$("[data-custom='other_container'] > input").attr('id', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only selects children of the selected element; it doesn't grab all  descendants (i.e. children of children, their children, and so on), which is what you want. In your example...

```
$("[data-custom='other_container']").children()
```

...only grabs the children of the other_container, i.e. your h3 and the div.container elements. Adding the 'input' filter will select no elements at all.

To find all descendants of a particular type, use jQuery's [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/). Your code could be rewritten as:

```
$("[data-custom='other_container']").find('input')
```

Lastly, keep in mind that all element IDs need to be unique. If they aren't, trying something like $('#this-id-is-not-unique') will frustrate you considerably. If you need to apply the same identifier to each of these inputs, consider adding a class to each element.